# Mathematica code for bifurcation diagram in 3D

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, modeling, ecology

Good day. I need help with the code in mathematica to plot the bifurcation diagram (`e vs z*`) or (`e vs x*`), for the system `x'[t]=x(1-x)-k1xy`,`y'[t]=ey(1-y)+k2xy-k3yz`,`z'[t]=-k4z+ek3yz`, where `X*=(x*,y*,z*)` is a fixed point of the system, with `k4=0.1,k1=0.02,k2=0.1,k3=1.2`, and `e`belongs to `[0,4]`.

Thank you

Comment: or the bifurcation diagram (e vs z), where z is a solution

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Patrick! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like a little three-species food web model -- a perfect excuse to use my new [EcoEvo package](https://github.com/cklausme/EcoEvo).

First, install the package (one-time only):

```
PacletInstall["https://github.com/cklausme/EcoEvo/releases/download/v1.0.1/EcoEvo-1.0.1.paclet"]
```

Then load the package and set the model for analysis with `SetModel`:

```
<< EcoEvo`

SetModel[{
  Pop[x] -> {Equation :> x[t] (1 - x[t]) - k1 x[t] y[t]},
  Pop[y] -> {Equation :> e y[t] (1 - y[t]) + k2 x[t] y[t] - k3 y[t] z[t]},
  Pop[z] -> {Equation :> -k4 z[t] + e k3 y[t] z[t]}
  }]
```

Set the parameters, then solve for the equilibria:

```
k4 = 0.1; k1 = 0.02; k2 = 0.1; k3 = 1.2;
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
```

[image]

Now you can plot the parts of the final, coexistence equilibrium vs `e`:

```
Plot[x /. eq[[-1]], {e, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {0, All}]
Plot[z /. eq[[-1]], {e, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {0, All}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Just for fun, you can simulate the model with `EcoSim`:

```
e = 1;
sol = EcoSim[{x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> 0.1}, 100];
PlotDynamics[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: There's a bug in your add-on: the documentation pages are asking for `/Users/klaus/Library/Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/MyStyleSheet.nb` !

Comment: @murray Ugh!  I'll try to fix it tonight.  Thanks for the note!

Comment: @murray If you have a chance, could you let me know if the updated version 1.0.1 fixes this problem for you?  (I tried on another computer and it looks promising).  Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisK: I just copied what you posted and was able to duplicate the results. I did get one error message: "Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result." Thanks.

Comment: @moo That's more of a warning than an error.

Comment: @ChrisK: I haven't reviewed this [package in detail, but is it possible to add a few examples of using it?

Comment: @Moo I put a few examples in the built-in docs - check out EcoEvo/tutorial/ExampleModels in the help browser.

Comment: @ChrisK: Beautifully documented! I noticed a slight typo "NyStreamPlot[f, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}]" (N instead of M). I would love to see so,mething like this added to the next release. I have tried doing 3D StreamPlots (which are very difficult) and they do not look good. It would also be great to have a 2D Bifurcation package that can generate those and everything related to them. Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99040/discussion-between-chris-k-and-moo).

Comment: @ChrisK: updated version 1.0.1 did fix the stylesheet problem with the documentation pages.

Comment: @Anovice That's just a warning if you load the package after having already used `t`.  Try starting a fresh kernel and loading the package first, and see if it goes away.